# regex iteration metacharacter * (asterisk) is not working

Tags: java, regex

Below regex code is written to replace String 01,02 to '01','02' or 01,02,03 to '01','02','03' etc.

```
String str = "01,02";

str = str.replaceAll("([^,]+)(,|$)", "'$1'$2");

// value of str successfully changed to '01','02'
```

But, it's not working with iteration metacharacter * instead of + as shown below

```
String str = "01,02";

str = str.replaceAll("([^,]*)(,|$)", "'$1'$2");

// value of str remains 01,02
```

Please clarify it. Also, is there any better regex matcher for above pattern.

Comment: If `"([^,]+)(,|$)"` is working for you then what's the problem then?

Comment: I am not understanding, why "([^,]*)(,|$)" is not working. I want to clarify my concepts.

Comment: When trying your second snippet, I don't get `01,02` but `'01','02'''`. You must be wrong somewhere. Let me know if you want some explanations about this result though.

Comment: Don't know how you are doing it but your 2nd regex will give you: `'01','02'''` as output. Which is result of `*` instead of `+` since it matches just before end also.

Comment: @AlexR See http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html, chapter "An Alternative to Laziness". To sum up, `.+?A` has to backtrack while `[^A]+` doesn't.

Comment: @sp00m I see. Thank you for the reference. I will delete my comment.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it now. I was wrongly using str.replace("([^,]*)(,|$)", "'$1'$2") instead of str.replaceAll(...) earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str = "01,02";

str = str.replaceAll("([^,]*)(,|$)", "'$1'$2");

System.out.println(str);
```

After running above I get

```
'01','02'''
```

because expression `([^,]*)(,|$)` means also match nothing and end of the line, this last statement will produce `''` string